# Jasper - No secret found for "XXXXX" key in "net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" category

Tags: java, java-8, jasper-reports

We use jasper with java 1.7 for report generation. It works fine with Java 1.7 version. Gets the below specified exception after java version updation to Java1.8.

**Issue**

```
No secret found for "XXXXXX" key in "net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" category.
```

Here "XXXXXX" is my database password.

My Database configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jdbcDataAdapter class="net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterImpl">
<name>DataAdapter</name>
<driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
<username>XXXX_user</username>
<password>XXXXX</password>
<savePassword>true</savePassword>
<url>jdbc:postgresql://XXXXXXX:5432/XXXXXdb</url>
<database></database>
<serverAddress></serverAddress>
</jdbcDataAdapter>
```

Unable to figuring out solution to the issue. Can anybody help to fix this issue?

Comment: Your Java version should have nothing to do with your issue. Did you also upgrade the JasperReports library?

Comment: Yes, I did it by  updating Current version of Jasperreport is 6.4.0 to 6.5.1.

Comment: So you're saying that in JR 6.4.0 your report with that adapter was working and that in JR 6.5.1 it does not work anymore?

Comment: Yes. Report does not work in JR 6.5.1 and Java 1.8.

Comment: But did it work in JR 6.4.0?

Comment: No It did not JR 6.4.0 , Java 1.8. but Works in JR 6.4.0 and Java 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Your issue should not be Java version related. It has to do with JasperReports configuration for handling passwords in data adapter files.

Passwords stored in plain text in data adapter files may raise security concerns.

That's why JasperReports relies on a  [`net.sf.jasperreports.util.SecretsProvider`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/jr-6-5-1/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/util/SecretsProvider.java) implementation for resolving passwords. This `SecretsProvider` needs to be plugged in through the extension mechanism. No provider is plugged in by default.

For production use, a proper `SecretsProvider` that decrypts passwords needs to be implemented and registered on your side.

For basic testing purposes you can register the built-in extension [`net.sf.jasperreports.util. IdentitySecretsProviderExtensionsRegistryFactory`](https://github.com/TIBCOSoftware/jasperreports/blob/jr-6-5-1/jasperreports/src/net/sf/jasperreports/util/IdentitySecretsProviderExtensionsRegistryFactory.java) by adding the following configuration to a `jasperreports_extension.properties` in the root of your classpath:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.identity.secrets.provider=net.sf.jasperreports.util.IdentitySecretsProviderExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.identity.secrets.category.da=net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter
```